# why one get "Platform declaration clash" but the other is fine?

Tags: kotlin

Having a interface defined:

```
interface IData {

    fun getHash() : Int
    fun getUUID(): UUID

    ......
}
```

Trying to create object for the interface.  the `fun getUUID(): UUID` is fine,  but the `fun getHash() : Int`  got error as below.

What might be wrong? why they are different?

```
fun buidlDataList () : ArrayList<IData> {

    val dataList = ArrayList<IData>(0)

    dataList.add(object : IData {

        val hash: Int by lazy { dataFetchers.size+System.currentTimeMillis().toInt() } //<=== get error
        override fun getHash(): Int {                                                  //<=== get the same error
            return hash
        }

        val uuid: UUID by lazy { UUID.randomUUID() }
        override fun getUUID(): UUID {
            return uuid
        }
        ......
    }
}


Platform declaration clash:  The following declarations have the same JVM signature(getHash() I):
    * public final fun <get-hash>(): int  defined in com.data. buidlDataList <no name provided>
    * public open fun getHash(): int defined in defined in com.data. buidlDataList <no name provided>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables create their own getters, but you also explicitly define them. When you declare a var or a val, they usually have their own getters automatically generated<sup>1</sup>. Private vals or vars don't, if you don't create a custom getter.

But in all other cases, this:

```
val x: Int = TODO()
```

generates a getter<sup>1</sup>.

In your case, I'd recommend using val in the interface directly. You see, the generated getter has the same name as the getHash method you explicitly declared. The getters don't override methods either (unless you annotate it with one of the @Jvm annotations, and I don't remember which, but you don't really need those anyways).

So you change your interface to:

```
interface IData {
    val hash: Int
    val uuid: UUID
}
```

And remove the getters in the overridden object, and add `override` to the vals:

```
dataList.add(object : IData {
    override val hash: Int by lazy { dataFetchers.size+System.currentTimeMillis().toInt() }
    override val uuid: UUID by lazy { UUID.randomUUID() }
}
```

The first interface is actually equivalent to declaring an interface with get and set methods. If you override it from Java, it will ask you to override `getHash()` and `getUid()`, and you need to declare the field locally. Kotlin works differently because it automatically generates setters.

And since you can declare variables in interfaces without messing up Java interop, I highly recommend you use that over @Jvm* annotations (mainly because it makes it easier to understand the code, though that's a personal preference).

---

Also, if you decompile the Kotlin bytecode, you'll see what the interface with the variables compiles to:

```
public interface IData {
   int getHash();

   @NotNull
   UUID getUuid();
}
```

So it's identical to the one you originally had, just without conflicts in child classes because of variable name clashes.

---

And the reason only one has a clash is because, as you see in the interface, `val uuid` creates a getter named `getUuid`, while your interface declares `getUUID`. Methods in Java and Kotlin are case-sensitive, which is why those don't clash. If you re-name your variable to upper-case `UUID`, you will get a clash on that too.

<sub>1: Assuming the variable/constant isn't in a method. Top-level variables, variables in interfaces, enums, classes, objects, and companion objects all generate getters/setters, but if you declare a variable inside a method, it naturaly won't have getters and setters where that applies.</sub>